# nvcc --version command says nvcc is not installed

Tags: 16.04, cuda

I have installed cuda8.0, the latest version. I followed the procedure provided by Nvidia; but, when I type the command `nvcc --version` it says nvcc is not installed!

What do I do now?

Comment: do a `which nvcc` see if it returns any thing...

Comment: No it didnt return

Comment: That means it didn't install well or is not in your `PATH`, find where it is with `whereis nvcc`..

Comment: it only displayed "nvcc: "

Comment: Close and launch terminal and try `nvcc --version` to be sure

Comment: No nothing happened

Comment: Please drop the link to the install instructions will check it out later, preparing kids for school. Do you remember where you installed it, the location, if not find with `locate nvcc` let know if it finds the files for it.

Comment: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/secure/Prod2/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf?autho=1487654578_c44068654439cc0cff93bb6b55a27826&file=CUDA_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf

Comment: ` locate nvcc ` :/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc<br>
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc.profile<br>
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/doc/html/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/doc/html/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/graphics
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/doc/html/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53972/discussion-between-george-and-user6889367).

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The problem is [ **based** on the link you provided ] you haven't added it in the `.bashrc`. file so it can be seen:

1. From the terminal:

   ```
    nano /home/username/.bashrc

    # or

    nano /home/$USER/.bashrc
   ```
2. Inside there add the following: (replace `cuda-8.0` with your version)

   ```
    export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
   ```
3. Then do the following to **save** and **close** the **editor**:

   ```
    On you keyboard press the following: 

    ctrl + o             --> save 
    enter or return key  --> accept changes
    ctrl + x             --> close editor
   ```
4. Now either do `source .bashrc` or `close and open another terminal`
5. Now run `nvcc --version`

Information:

- `.bashrc`: is the file read by the `terminal` before opening and its found in the `/home/$USER` diretory of the user in question.
- the `.` before the file means its **hidden from view** unless you instruct your file manager to show `hidden` files

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 15):

The above solution by [@George Udosen](https://askubuntu.com/a/885627/618353) is fine. If you want to save the manual procedure, you can automate it by the following:

1. Create a file `add_to_bashrc` and add the following to it:

   ```
   export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
   export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_HOME/bin
   ```
2. Create a shell script `automate.sh`:

   ```
   (... some installation procedure ...)

   cat add_to_bashrc >> ~/.bashrc
   . ~/.bashrc
   ```
3. Then you just need to run your shell script:

   ```
   sh automate.sh
   ```
4. Don't forget to check if the CUDA's shortcut (symLink) works correctly. Simply execute:

   ```
   ls /usr/local/cuda
   ```

Answer (score 7):

For later versions of CUDA (11.7 for me), I followed the below steps:

1. Go to https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads and follow the installation instructions.
2. Inside the `~/.bashrc` file, update the path as follows:

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin:$PATH"`
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
   ```
3. The output of `nvcc -V` then looks like:

   ```
   nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
   Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
   Built on Wed_Jun__8_16:49:14_PDT_2022
   Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.99
   Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31442593_0
   ```

Answer (score 6):

The [answer from @George Udosen](https://askubuntu.com/a/885627/618353) is perfect.

Just for increment it, you can also export to `/usr/local/cuda` which is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/cuda-10.1`, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54953476/8682939). So, you can also write:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}$ 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Terminal:

`sudo gedit /home/$USER/.bashrc`

Add at the end of the file

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_HOME/bin
```

Then terminal:

`source .bashrc`

Now run

`nvcc --version`

Comment: This is not an answer. All you have here is a repeat of the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't deny that, but I believe my answer can help many people struggling to edit the path correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution by @Agile Bean is fine. If you want to you can use the env var CUDA_HOME instead of /usr/local/cuda in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and edit your .bashrc or .zshrc file or the resource file for your shell with emacs or vi or nano or your favorite editor:

1. emacs $HOME/.zshrc
2. Add the following lines to the .zshrc file
   export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda

export LD_LIBRARY_PATHlrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Sep 11 19:59 =$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib64:$CUDA_HOME/extras/CUPTI/lib64

export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_HOME/bin

3. Then open a new shell or source your shell's resource file (e.g. source .zshrc) from the current shell.

(base) ➜  ~ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jun__8_16:49:14_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.99
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31442593_0
(base) ➜  ~ which nvcc
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc

Where is cuda really located?
Let's follow the symbolic links to find out.

(base) ➜  ~ ls -ld /usr/local/cuda

/usr/local/cuda -> /etc/alternatives/cuda

(base) ➜  ~ ls -ld /etc/alternatives/cuda

/etc/alternatives/cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-11.7

Answer (score 0):

I am using Asus VivoBook X540UBR (date: 01/08/2020) which comes with entry level NVIDIA GeForce MX110.

2 years ago, I abandoned Windows 10 and re-installed the notebook with Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon.

To my surprise, Linux has properly installed and maintained NVIDIA drivers via

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

I don't need to explicitly install Cuda toolkit from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local nor explicitly configure the environment path.

However, I installed Cuda toolkit as hinted by **apt** via

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Then, my GPU environment is ready.

To check the Cuda version in Ubuntu/Mint:

```
$ nvidia-smi
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.161.07  Driver Version: 535.161.07  CUDA Version: 12.2    |
|----------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
... (ignore the rest) ...
```

To check whether Cuda toolkit is installed:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Nov_18_09:45:30_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.119
Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30672275_0
```

I am in the middle of studying https://youtu.be/Z_ikDlimN6A?t=4906 and installed pytorch=1.10.0.

```
>>> import torch
>>> print(torch.cuda.is_available())
>>> print(torch.__version__)

True
1.10.0
```