# Nvcc is not found while cuda is installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I'm trying to get `nvcc` working, but it seems that it's not even installed on my system. Although I have installed `cuda-10.2` when installing pytorch with conda, but there's no mention of `nvcc` at all anywhere and `which nvcc` returns nothing. I searched the related threads and noticed that nvcc should be in path: `/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin/nvcc`, but interestingly, there's not any `bin/` folder within `cuda-10.2/`, let alone `nvcc`. If it was, I'd have add them to the `bashsrc`.

Does anyone know the solution to this? `nvcc` is supposed to be used by a library that I'm using, but since it cannot fetch it, it just stops working.

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/885610/nvcc-version-command-says-nvcc-is-not-installed

Comment: Already tried, not working for me @ShubhangKakkar; those solution assumes there's `bin` folder within `cuda` folder, but I even do not have this `bin` folder which I can point to...

Comment: why dont you try reinstalling @inverted_index

Comment: you mean reinstalling `cuda` toolkit? I feel like it's been installed with conda pytorch. Re-installing it (at least in this way) doesn't cause `nvcc` to appear within cuda folder. Do you know a better way of installing cuda? @ShubhangKakkar

Comment: No sorry unfortunately I don't know

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348006/nvcc-is-not-found-while-cuda-is-installed  The .run file allows you to skip the Nvidia driver install, and to override the location for bin and lib files (select ...cuda10.2/bin, etc.).

Comment: Conda tends to do things differently from the regular cuda install - perhaps this is relevant [Nvcc missing when installing cudatoolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470424/nvcc-missing-when-installing-cudatoolkit)

Comment: @steeldriver thank you for providing the link. Seems that the last answer is sort of useful, but unfortunately `cudatoolkit-dev` doesn't have 10.2 ...